# OpenGL: What's the deal with deprecation?

Tags: opengl, deprecated, opengl-3

OpenGL 3.0 and 3.1 have deprecated quite a few features I find essential. In particular, the use of fixed function in shaders.

Can anyone explain what's really the deal with that?

Why do they find the need to deprecate such useful feature that its obvious everybody uses and that no sane hardware company is going to remove support for?

Answer (score 7):

As you said, no hardware company will remove support for fixed-function shaders, because there are so many existing applications that use them. What they don't want to do, though, is figure out how to specify the interactions between FF shaders and every future extension they add. Those interactions are very complicated (partly because FF shaders are so complicated), which leads to bugs and inconsistent implementations between vendors -- both of which are bad for developers and end users.

So they're drawing a line: if you want to use FF shaders, you don't get any of the new functionality. If you want new functionality, you can't use FF shaders. This is very similar to what Microsoft did in D3D10: it added a whole bunch of new functionality, but at the same time completely removed fixed-function shaders. The belief is that the set of developers who need the new non-shader functionality but who don't also need programmable shaders is very small.

Comment: Didn't they say they were planning on removing the functionality from future OpenGL versions?

Answer (score 2):

It should be clarified that a feature that is marked "deprecated" is not actually removed.  For example, an OpenGL 3.0 context has all of the features - nothing is gone.  Further, some vendors will ship drivers that can create 3.1 and 3.2 contexts using a compatibility profile which will also enable the deprecated features.  So, look closely at what vendor hardware you are going to support and ask about the ARB compatibility mode for old features.  (There is also the "core" profile as of 3.2, which allows vendors to create a more lean and mean driver if they wish to make such a thing)

Note that any current card really doesn't have an FF hardware section any more - they only run shaders.  When you ask for FF behavior, the GL runtime is authoring shaders on your behalf..

Comment: "the GL runtime is authoring shaders on your behalf.".... Do you have any references for that?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  Just conversations with IHV driver people.

Comment: Using deprecated functionality in general is a bad idea. A feature becomes deprecated to indicate you shouldn't use it and it may be removed in the (near) future. You'd better invest time in learning about the alternatives so you are ready for it when this feature actually is removed.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do they find the need to deprecate such useful feature that its obvious everybody uses and that no sane hardware company is going to remove support for?

I suppose then Apple must be insane, because MacOSX 10.7 supports only 3.2 *core*. No compatibility specification support, no ARB_compatibility extension, nothing. You can either create a 2.1 context or a 3.2 core context.

However, if you want reasons:

1. For the sake of completeness: what Jesse Hall said. The ARB no longer has to consider the interaction between fixed function and new features. Integer math, array textures, and various other features are defined to not be usable with the fixed function pipeline. OpenGL has really improved over the last 3 years since GL 3.0 came out; the pace of the ARB's changes is quite substantial. Would that have been possible if they had to find a way to make all of those features interact with fixed function? And if they didn't have fixed function interactions, would you not then be complaining how you can't access new features from your old code? Which leads nicely into:
2. It serves as a strong indication of what one *ought* to be using. Even if the compatibility context is always available, you can look at core OpenGL to see how one ought to be approaching problem solving.
3. It makes the eventual desktop GL and GL ES unification much more reasonable. ES 2.0 threw out all of the old stuff and just adopted what you might think of as core GL 2.1. The ultimate goal will be to only have one OpenGL. To do that, you have to be able to rid the desktop GL of all of the cruft.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed function shaders are quite easily replaced with standard GLSL shaders so it's difficult to see why logically they shouldn't be deprecated.

I'm less certain than you that they won't be dropped from much hardware in the foreseeable future as OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support the FF pipeline (and so isn't backward compatible with OpenGL ES 1.x).  It seems to me that much of the momentum with OpenGL these days is coming from the widespread adoption of OpenGL ES on mobile platforms and with FF functionality gone from there there will be some considerable pressure to move away from it's use.

Indeed I'd expect the leaner OpenGL ES implementation to replace standard OpenGL quite widely over the next few years, and FF functionality may disappear more because most hardware will implement OpenGL ES rather than because it's removed from hardware implementing the full OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL allows for both a 'core' profile and a 'compatibly' profile. So for most systems you wont loose any kind of access to deprecated or removed functions.

But if you want to ensure compatibly it is best to stick to the core stuff. You won't be guaranteed a compatibility profile (even if most hardware has one and at the current state it's more likely you will encounter an out of date OpenGL rather than a core only one). Also OpenGL ES is now a subset of OpenGL, it is possible to write a OpenGL ES 2.x/3.x program and have it run in OpenGL 4.3 with almost no changes.

Game console like the PlayStations and the Nintendo ones shipped with their own graphics libraries rather than using OpenGL.

They were based on OpenGL but here stripped down in a similar was to ES (I don't think ES 2.0 was out then). Those systems need to write their own graphics drivers and libraries, asking a hardware vendor to write what is basically a whole load of legacy wrapping libraries is a bit much (all the fixed function stuff would just end up being implemented in shaders at some stage and it's likely that glBegin/glEnd would just be getting turned into a VBO automatically anyway).

I think it has also been important to ensure that developers are made aware of the current way they should be programming. For decades people have been taught the 'wrong' way to do things by default and vertex buffer objects have been taught as an extra.