# glTranslate/rotate/scale vs Matrices in uniforms

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm working on a 3D game engine, and I've been using a shader with a mat4 uniform to send transformation info and camera info to the pipeline. I've seen examples online where people have been using only the glTranslatef(), glRotatef and stuff like that. Which method is the most accepted method?

Comment: Matrices in shader are not comparable with glTranslatef(),glRotatef() because these methods are just concept used in tranforming. and matrices in shader codes can be anything. In OpenGL, there are two pipelines fixed and programable first case is the fixed type and using shader is much more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using the uniforms in shaders going forward, as the functions like `glTranslatef()`, `glRotatef()`, etc. are part of what's known as the "fixed function pipeline". The fixed function pipeline is deprecated in modern OpenGL, meaning your code that uses it will not work with newer versions of OpenGL and OpenGL ES. There's a discussion of the implications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218449/opengl-whats-the-deal-with-deprecation).

Answer (score 1):

The above answer really is correct, and to be honest, I think the biggest drawback to using the old system is it's not flexible enough and you cannot do as many fun things with shaders. The new pipeline is all about allowing the programmer access to the shaders that control the data that is sent through the GPU, and as such, the new "standard" requires you to pretty much do all the hard stuff yourself. Besides actually rasterizing the vertices of course!